# Responsive Image Resize in Popup ... Tall images get cutoff

Tags: css, image

So, I have a popup that opens for a gallery. The width of the image in the popup is set to 100%, stretching to fit it's containing div. And, the height is set to auto, so the height will resize, depending on the width (same ratio). This is great for wide images ... but for tall images, the tall images get cutoff at the bottom of the page. If the height is too tall (and the image is cutoff), then I want the height to shrink to a different size, and the width to adjust. I tried max-height, but that skews the image ratio (shrinking the height, but not affecting the width). Anyone have a better solution?

You can see the problem here:
[Webpage](http://66.63.173.13/136-madison-place-ridgewood/#gallery)

Click the image of the outside white door, with the flower bushes (the 8th image). You will see that the image is too tall for the page, and gets cut off at the fold.

Here is an image of the issue
[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to have a CSS-only solution? Are you able to use Javascript?
If you can use Javascript you could add a condition to see if the height of the image is bigger than the window height and in this case add a class to change the behavior of the image.

```
var img = document.querySelector("img"); // Add correct selector here

if ( img.height > window.innerHeight ) {

    img.classList.add("maxHeight");
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.maxHeight {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: I have alot of images on my site, so I can't use querySelector("img") because I dont want to mess with other images on the site (just the popup image).  However, if I just go in and change height:100% and width:auto, this still doesn't solve the problem. The image width is a little smaller, but the height still extends below the fold.

Comment: That's why I added a comment on the first line that you habe to change the selector to match this image. I think in this case what you have to do first is to set a max-height for the container and afterwards do the calculation to shrink the image